# Relation not found error with play and postgres (while table does exists)

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, playframework

I have a table called ETL_TABLES which resides on the public schema. In
my application.conf I have the following line:

```
hibernate.default_schema=public
```

that should mean the search_path of postgres is set to the public schema.

I have a class `Tables`, with the `@Table(name="ETL_TABLES")` annotation.
But when I try to access the entity class, for example by
`Tables.findAll();` then the error says relation "public.etl_tables"
does not exist.

The table is present on the postgres public schema, so what am I doing
wrong here ?

Comment: Which server are you connecting to? Could it be you're connecting to another server, eg localhost?

Comment: Most probably a name case problem - quoted and all caps on creation and unquoted (and thus all lower-case) on use. More info - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS (look for "quoted identifier")

Comment: Can I make sure that hibernate uses the quoted and all caps option. I did use caps in the @Table annotation. The query that is generated by hibernate is select tables0_.ID as ID0_, tables0_.COPY as COPY0_, tables0_.QUERY as QUERY0_, tables0_.TABLENAME as TABLENAME0_ from public.ETL_TABLES tables0_

Comment: @Bohemian , I connect to the test database we have. wich is the same connection i have in PGAdmin (since it's the only postgres database we have at the moment)

Comment: Check your connection properties - it would be unusual to not specify the schema and rely on the default. Check your config files etc.

Comment: My connection properties in de play framework application.conf are ,where etl is the database name. With the hibernate.default_schema the schema should be set to public.db.url=jdbc:postgresql://pgs-o:5433/etl
db.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.user=****
db.pass=****

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently in our configuration I need to write this when creating an entity:

```
@Table(name="\"ETL_TABLES\"")
```

So I have to use \" to represent the double quotes needed in the select.

Comment: This suggests that the table was created with the name double-quoted, making it case sensitive. Any reference to upper or mixed case object names need to be double-quoted since PostgreSQL defaults object names to lower-case.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have set postgresql dialect:

```
jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: Already have a line jpa.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect in my application.conf

Comment: maybe what you need is the line: hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem and turns out that hibernate doesn't like mapped table names in entity by default (I am sure there is some configuration somewhere to override this !). So It can't find the relation 'Article' but will find 'article' or 'ARTICLE'. Hope this helps folks who come to this thread