# How to query a table with name having both upper and lower case?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

If the table name is something like `userStatus`, in Postgres it becomes all lower case => `userstatus`.

The query is:

```
String query = "FROM userStatus"
```

But it does not work, and it does not work with "`FROM \"userStatus\"`" either.

Comment: `"userStatus"` should work, **if** the table was created that way: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the table in question. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6815773/330315